# Upload blob with AJAX and move file in the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I started the project to create a social network with my little programming skills, but I'm stuck:
I want to create a posting system like Facebook / Instagram, but the problem is, I want to be able to upload images given by my users to the server directly and not to the database. So I first looked for a way I needed to preview the image, for that I converted the image to Base64 using JS then, I displayed it in my img tag. Then users could submit the form, that's where it gets complicated, because if I understood correctly, you have to convert the image into a Blob to be sent by AJAX so that's what I do in JS except that after it arrived in the PHP file I couldn't find a way to turn it back to Base64 as I realized that PHP doesn't support Blobs or if it does manage it then I was wrong, and I have not found a way to exploit this technology in PHP. So here I am, sending the data is working, no problem, but I still can't upload the images to my server directly, so I tried doing a `base64_encode();` but it didn't work, then I tried multiple code from the whole web, but it still didn't work. I saw that on this site there were multiple questions that demand for the same help, but after reading them all well, but in practice it still didn't work, so hopefully I could find some help here and my code after will work. I leave you the code below, and thank you for reading everything. :)
Sorry I forgot two things, I wouldn't want to use jQuery in my code, that's why if you give me jQuery I'll try to translate to normal JS, but it's going to be rather difficult so if you don't mind please do not use jQuery. And for the second thing please forgive my English I am a French in high school passionate about code and given that the whole site is in English I did not allow myself to write in French :)
My code :

```
var getHttpRequest = function () {

     var httpRequest = false;

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //Mozilla,Safari,...

          httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

          if (httpRequest.overrideMimeType) {

               httpRequest.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

          }

     }

     else if (window.ActiveXObject) { //IE

          try {
               httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }

          catch (e) {
                         
               try{

                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }

               catch (e) {}
          }
     }
     if (!httpRequest) {
          alert('Abandon :( Impossible de créer une instance XMLHTTP');
          return false;
     }

     return httpRequest;
}
function creapubimg(){
    let httpRequest = getHttpRequest();
    let content = document.getElementById('content_text_area_img').value;
    let imgpub = document.getElementById('chosen-image').src;
    let extention = ['jpeg','png','jpg','gif'];
    let base64ImageContent,contentType,hashtxt;
    var contentTypepost
    let idcountforinclude=0;
    extention.forEach(element => {
        if (imgpub.indexOf(element.value) !== -1){
            base64ImageContent = imgpub.replace('data:image/'+element.value+';base64');
            switch (element.value) {
                case 'jpeg':
                case 'jpg':
                    contentTypepost = 2;
                    contentType = 'image/jpeg'
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    contentTypepost = 3;
                    contentType = 'image/png'
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    contentTypepost = 1;
                    contentType = 'image/gif'
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    let base64 = imgpub.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', "");
    let blob = b64toBlob(base64,contentType);
    let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    hashtxt = makeid(24);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(httpRequest.readyState === 1){
          hide_img_panel_reverse();
        }
        if(httpRequest.readyState === 2){
          // faire apparaitre truc de chargment
        }
        if(httpRequest.readyState === 4){
            if(httpRequest.responseText != 'veuiller remplir tout les champs'){
                idcountforinclude += 1;
                let docu = document.getElementById('aff_pub');
                // hide truc de chargment
                let replt = document.createElement('div');
                replt.setAttribute('id', idcountforinclude);
                docu.prepend(replt);
                document.getElementById(idcountforinclude).innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    httpRequest.open('POST','includes/createpubimg.php',true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send("content_publiction=" + encodeURIComponent(content) + "&img=" + encodeURIComponent(blob) + "&string=" + encodeURIComponent(hashtxt) + "&Content-Type=" + encodeURIComponent(contentTypepost));
}
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType='',sliceSize=512){
    let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    let byteArrays = [];
    for(let offset = 0; offset <  byteCharacters.length; offset+=sliceSize){
        
        let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset,offset + sliceSize);
        let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

And here is the PHP :

```
<?php
include '../database.php';
        global $db;

if(isset($_POST['img'])){
  if($_POST['Content-Type'] == 1) {
    $hashchemin = crypt($_POST['string'], 'piafou');
    $hashchemin = rtrim($hashchemin, '/\\');
    $chemin = 'img_pub/'.$hashchemin.'.gif';  
    if(isset($_POST['content_publication'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['content_publication'])){
        $content = $_POST['content_publication'];
        $Blobimg = $_POST['file'];
        $Base64img = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($Blobimg) . "";
        move_uploaded_file(base64_decode($Base64img), $chemin);
        $ins = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO publications (content, img_pub) VALUES (:content, :img_pub)');
        $ins->execute([
          'content' => $content,
          'img_pub' => $chemin
        ]);
        $publications =$db->query('SELECT * FROM publications ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 60');
        $pub = $publications->fetch();
        ?>
          <div class="aff_pub_div_content" id="<?=$pub['id']?>">
            <div style="height: 52px;">
              <img class="nonSelectionnable" height="48px" width="48px" src="IMG/favicon.png" style="float: left; margin-left: 16px">
              <label class="nonSelectionnable" style="float: left; margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 12px;font-size: 20px;">Nerzus</label>
              <a class="button-edit nonSelectionnable" onclick="hide_edit_panel(<?= $pub['id'] ?>)" style="text-decoration: none; color: #807c7cc4; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 12.6px; float: right; cursor: pointer;">●●●</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nonSelectionnable">
              <?php if(!empty($pub['img_pub'])){ ?>
                <img src="<?=$pub['img_pub']?>" class="img_pub_aff">
              <?php 
                  }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p class="text_pub_aff" id="<?="content_".$pub['id']?>">
                <?php 
                  $pub_content = $_POST['content_publication'];
                  $pub_content = htmlspecialchars($pub_content, ENT_HTML5);
                  $pub_content = nl2br($pub_content);
                  echo($pub_content);
                ?>  
              </p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#d6d6dd;height:1px;width:96%;margin-top:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"></div>
            <div style="text-align: left;" class="nonSelectionnable">
              <ul style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 20px">
                <?php 
                  $likepub = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :pub AND user = :user');
                  $likepub->execute([
                    'user' => 16,
                    'pub' => $pub['id']
                  ]);
                  if($likepub->rowCount() ==1) {
                ?> 
                <style type="text/css">
                  .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                    background-color: red;
                  }
                </style>
                <?php
                  }
                  else{
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                  .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                    background-color: white;
                  }
                </style>
                <?php
                  }
                ?>
                <li class="exp_article" style="margin-right: 6px">
                  <div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="like_article phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>" id="like-div-<?=$pub['id']?>">
                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="like_db(16,<?=$pub['id']?>,<?=$pub['id']?>);">
                      <img src="IMG/love.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="like">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="exp_article" style="color: black;font-size: 24px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;;vertical-align: top;margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 16px;" id="likepart-<?=$pub['id']?>"><?php $idpublike = $pub['id'];$likerecup = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :id');$likerecup->execute(['id' => $idpublike]);$likecount = $likerecup->rowCount();echo $likecount;?></li>
                <li class="exp_article">
                  <div style="background-color:white;height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="comment_article" id="comment-div-<?=$pub['id']?>"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="comment_aff(<?=$pub['id']?>);"><img src="IMG/chat-bubble.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="comment"></a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
      }
      else{
        echo('Veuiller remplir tout les champs');
      } 
    }
  }
  elseif($_POST['Content-Type'] == 2){
    $hashchemin = crypt($_POST['string'], 'piafou');
    $hashchemin = rtrim($hashchemin, '/\\');
    $chemin = 'img_pub/'.$hashchemin.'.jpeg';
    if(isset($_POST['content_publication'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['content_publication'])){
        $content = $_POST['content_publication']; 
        $Blobimg = $_POST['file'];
        $Base64img = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($Blobimg) . "";
        move_uploaded_file(base64_decode($Base64img), $chemin);
        $ins = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO publications (content, img_pub) VALUES (:content, :img_pub)');
        $ins->execute([
          'content' => $content,
          'img_pub' => $chemin
        ]);
        $publications =$db->query('SELECT * FROM publications ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 60');
        $pub = $publications->fetch();
        ?>
          <div class="aff_pub_div_content" id="<?=$pub['id']?>">
            <div style="height: 52px;">
                <img class="nonSelectionnable" height="48px" width="48px" src="IMG/favicon.png" style="float: left; margin-left: 16px">
                <label class="nonSelectionnable" style="float: left; margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 12px;font-size: 20px;">Nerzus</label>
                <a class="button-edit nonSelectionnable" onclick="hide_edit_panel(<?= $pub['id'] ?>)" style="text-decoration: none; color: #807c7cc4; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 12.6px; float: right; cursor: pointer;">●●●</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nonSelectionnable">
              <?php if(!empty($pub['img_pub'])){ ?>
                <img src="<?=$pub['img_pub']?>" class="img_pub_aff">
              <?php 
                  }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p class="text_pub_aff" id="<?="content_".$pub['id']?>">
                <?php 
                  $pub_content = $_POST['content_publication'];
                  $pub_content = htmlspecialchars($pub_content, ENT_HTML5);
                  $pub_content = nl2br($pub_content);
                  echo($pub_content);
                ?>  
              </p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#d6d6dd;height:1px;width:96%;margin-top:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"></div>
            <div style="text-align: left;" class="nonSelectionnable">
              <ul style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 20px">
                <?php 
                  $likepub = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :pub AND user = :user');
                  $likepub->execute([
                    'user' => 16,
                    'pub' => $pub['id']
                  ]);
                  if($likepub->rowCount() ==1) {
                ?> 
                <style type="text/css">
                  .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                    background-color: red;
                  }
                </style>
                <?php
                  }
                  else{
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                  .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                    background-color: white;
                  }
                </style>
                <?php
                  }
                ?>
                <li class="exp_article" style="margin-right: 6px">
                  <div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="like_article phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>" id="like-div-<?=$pub['id']?>">
                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="like_db(16,<?=$pub['id']?>,<?=$pub['id']?>);">
                      <img src="IMG/love.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="like">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="exp_article" style="color: black;font-size: 24px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;;vertical-align: top;margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 16px;" id="likepart-<?=$pub['id']?>"><?php $idpublike = $pub['id'];$likerecup = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :id');$likerecup->execute(['id' => $idpublike]);$likecount = $likerecup->rowCount();echo $likecount;?></li>
                <li class="exp_article">
                  <div style="background-color:white;height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="comment_article" id="comment-div-<?=$pub['id']?>"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="comment_aff(<?=$pub['id']?>);"><img src="IMG/chat-bubble.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="comment"></a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
      }
      else{
        echo('Veuiller remplir tout les champs');
      } 
    } 
  }
  elseif($_POST['Content-Type'] == 3){
    $hashchemin = crypt($_POST['string'], 'piafou');
    $hashchemin = rtrim($hashchemin, '/\\');
    $chemin = 'img_pub/'.$hashchemin.'.png';
    if(isset($_POST['content_publication'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['content_publication'])){
        $content = $_POST['content_publication'];
        $Blobimg = $_POST['file'];
        $Base64img = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($Blobimg) . "";
        move_uploaded_file(base64_decode($Base64img), $chemin);
        $ins = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO publications (content, img_pub) VALUES (:content, :img_pub)');
        $ins->execute([
          'content' => $content,
          'img_pub' => $chemin
        ]);
        $publications =$db->query('SELECT * FROM publications ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 60');
        $pub = $publications->fetch();
        ?>
          <div class="aff_pub_div_content" id="<?=$pub['id']?>">
              <div style="height: 52px;">
                  <img class="nonSelectionnable" height="48px" width="48px" src="IMG/favicon.png" style="float: left; margin-left: 16px">
                  <label class="nonSelectionnable" style="float: left; margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 12px;font-size: 20px;">Nerzus</label>
                  <a class="button-edit nonSelectionnable" onclick="hide_edit_panel(<?= $pub['id'] ?>)" style="text-decoration: none; color: #807c7cc4; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 12.6px; float: right; cursor: pointer;">●●●</a>
              </div>
              <div class="nonSelectionnable">
                <?php if(!empty($pub['img_pub'])){ ?>
                  <img src="<?=$pub['img_pub']?>" class="img_pub_aff">
                <?php 
                    }
                ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="text_pub_aff" id="<?="content_".$pub['id']?>">
                  <?php 
                    $pub_content = $_POST['content_publication'];
                    $pub_content = htmlspecialchars($pub_content, ENT_HTML5);
                    $pub_content = nl2br($pub_content);
                    echo($pub_content);
                  ?>  
                </p>
              </div>
              <div style="background-color:#d6d6dd;height:1px;width:96%;margin-top:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"></div>
              <div style="text-align: left;" class="nonSelectionnable">
                <ul style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 20px">
                  <?php 
                    $likepub = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :pub AND user = :user');
                    $likepub->execute([
                      'user' => 16,
                      'pub' => $pub['id']
                    ]);
                    if($likepub->rowCount() ==1) {
                  ?> 
                  <style type="text/css">
                    .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                      background-color: red;
                    }
                  </style>
                  <?php
                    }
                    else{
                  ?>
                  <style type="text/css">
                    .phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>{
                      background-color: white;
                    }
                  </style>
                  <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                  <li class="exp_article" style="margin-right: 6px">
                    <div style="height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="like_article phpdecidelikecolordiv-<?=$pub['id']?>" id="like-div-<?=$pub['id']?>">
                      <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="like_db(16,<?=$pub['id']?>,<?=$pub['id']?>);">
                        <img src="IMG/love.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="like">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="exp_article" style="color: black;font-size: 24px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;;vertical-align: top;margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 16px;" id="likepart-<?=$pub['id']?>"><?php $idpublike = $pub['id'];$likerecup = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM like_pub WHERE pub = :id');$likerecup->execute(['id' => $idpublike]);$likecount = $likerecup->rowCount();echo $likecount;?></li>
                  <li class="exp_article">
                    <div style="background-color:white;height: 30px;width: 30px;" class="comment_article" id="comment-div-<?=$pub['id']?>"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="comment_aff(<?=$pub['id']?>);"><img src="IMG/chat-bubble.png" height="30px" width="30px" id="comment"></a></div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        <?php
      }
      else{
        echo('Veuiller remplir tout les champs');
      } 
    }
  }
  else{
    // message d'erreur
  }
}
?>
```

You can see that in my PHP code I put this:

```
$Base64img = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($Blobimg) . "";
```

It is thanks to this line of code that I believed that I would succeed in converting the blob to Base64
If anyone has the solution to my problem, I thank them in advance.
P.S. = I have already tried with Form Data and I have not succeeded I think this is the solution, but I cannot get it to work.
Thanks to everyone who read :)

Comment: If you upload it as a blob it will be in the PHP $_FILES array, not in the $_POST array.

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL` is just turning it back into base64. You're converting it to base64, then to  a blob, then back to base64.

Comment: whta's going on here: `imgpub.replace('data:image/'+element.value+';base64');` the replace method takes 2 arguments you're only giving it one.

Comment: `element` is a string. it does not have a `value` property.

Comment: You can't url encode a blob. a blob is not a string.

Comment: these are all errors you should have seen in the browser console. I suggest you learn how to use the console and come back with a specific question or error rather than just throwing spaghetti code at us and asking us to rewrite it for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the `$ _FILES` but with me, it does not work to test I change my code at the beginning part                                                                                ` <? Php
include '../database.php';
global $ db;
if (isset ($ _ FILES ['img'])) {
echo "test1";`
If this had worked I would have received test1, which is not the case, I think it is due to `encodeURIComponent ()` but how not to use it I therefore have to use `$ _POST`.

Comment: For `URL.createObjectURL` I don't understand what you mean in the sense that this code will create a direct link to display the image in the browser its presence in this code was only experimental, please me apologize for leaving it. But for the fact that I start from an image in Base64 and then convert it to Blob to convert it back to Base64, it's because I couldn't find any other way to upload it to my server.

Comment: 1) you're not upload a blob. You're code is probably throwing errors before it uploads anything at all. 2) there are too many errors here to be addressed in a single SO question. Your first step at this point is to learn how to use the console. You simply cannot build something like this without learning the console.

Comment: Excuse me, here is the code to modify in JS : https://code.empreintesduweb.com/14759.html

Comment: However, the console does not indicate to me a specific problem, it only indicates to me that nothing has been received from my PHP script, because there was an error in it, because the download of the image on the server did not work, in other hand, if it is not possible to upload a blob to the server, explain to me how to do in general terms to upload to the server an image send by AJAX. For me to do my research then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use base64 for file upload. With a large file, your base64 will be extremely large. Although base64 is a relatively efficient way of encoding binary data it will, on average still increase the file size by more than 25%. This increases your bandwidth bill and uploads time. Instead, use the form data to upload the file. Just use base64 to preview the file before upload.

You also don't need to implement an XMLHttpRequest yourself (unless you want your code to work in IE :D) use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

```html
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file" onchange="readFile()" /> 
  <button id="upload-button" onclick="uploadFile()"> Upload </button>
  <script>

   function readFile() {
  
     if(this.files && this.files[0]) {
    
       const fileReader = new FileReader();
    
       fileReader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        //you can use base64 to preview file
        console.log('Base64:', e.target.result);
       }); 
    
       fileReader.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
     }
  
   }


   function uploadFile() {
      const formData = new FormData(); 
      const fileUploadInput = document.getElementById('file-upload');
      formData.append("file", fileUploadInput.files[0]);
      
      fetch('/upload.php', {
        method: "POST", 
        body: formData
      })
      .then(() => {
       console.log('Success');
      })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }
  </script>
```

In PHP code, you can get the file from a global variable `$_FILES`

```
<?php
// upload.php
var_dump($_FILES['file']);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it almost works, I just have a question, when I want to upload $ _FILES ['file'] to the server, I get an error, because as I understood it is an array this variable and not a string. So parameter 1 is considered an error. What variable should I put in parameter 1. Because as far as I know, we cannot take a variable which is already in a sub-variable in an array, right?

Comment: And also I get an error in the console:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
What I don't understand in your code is why you want to interpret the response as a JSON.

Comment: Oh sorry , i updated my example

Comment: The type of $_FILES is an array, the index of each element in $_FILES is the key you added in the form data.
In my example: the key is `file`.
When accessing an element in an array of PHP the syntax will be $array[key].
The structure of the element in $_FILES when you use the var_dump function will be:
Array(
[name] => 8f472e07e1e52bbb72f4.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => /tmp/phps8Eikx
[error] => 0
[size] => 713217
).
Now you can use move_uploaded_file to move the file to the directory to be stored.
Save the path of the file to the database.

Comment: I noticed that there was a problem with uploading to the server, the tmp_name is empty, so we cannot upload the image to the server:                                                    array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '20211123_102435198_iOS.jpg' (length=26)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 1
      'size' => int 0

Comment: I must therefore use a code other than: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $chemin);`

Comment: base64 & filereader should not even be used to preview files, that's what object urls are for... `URL.createObjectURL(file)` it's much faster